# Неверная ссылка в статье faq-а о модераторах?

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, справка

**Дано:**

Статья в FAQ-е о [модераторах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators). В её конце есть строка вида *"Узнайте, кто является модераторами этого сайта, или просмотрите список модераторов на всех сайтах Stack Exchange."* В ней две ссылки: [первая, кто является модераторами этого сайта](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), и [вторая, список модераторов на всех сайтах](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).

**Проблема:**

По второй ссылке релевантная информация, а по первой повтор уже имеющейся в тексте статьи ссылки на *"A Theory of Moderation"* (статья о модерации на англо-саксонском).

**Вопрос:**

Таки должно что-то другое быть по первой ссылке (список модераторов ru-SO), и нынче мы наблюдаем ошибку копи-паста?

Comment: Юрий, что-то вы увлеклись меткой [meta-tag:нытьё]. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin у меня к ней необъяснимые нежные чувства)

Comment: ок. Но на мои вопросы больше не добавляйте. Можете перечитать описание, если сомневаетесь.

Comment: Хорошо, больше не буду)

Comment: Оформление в виде `кода` следует использовать только для идентификаторов и небольших кусочков кода. В других случаях подобное выделение избыточно (в частности, в случае названий и заголовков). Обычно названия и заголовки никак отдельно не выделяются, достаточно заглавных букв. Если нужно поставить акцент, можно использовать курсив. / Тег "нытьё", раз уж он так всем нравится, для обсуждения проблем в общей форме, а тут конкретный баг, ноль нытья. Если хочется использовать тег, то ныть надо больше.

Comment: Про выделение кода согласен - писал сей вопрос ещё до осознания этого. А нытьё было по тому, что мне было никак не найти список модераторов, что вгоняло меня в уныние... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первой ссылке должна быть вот [эта ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators):

```
ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators
```

В подтверждение: на англоязычном SO [именно так](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: Угу, спс. А я плохо искал или нужны особые права для правки FAQ-a?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: [Как редактировать справку?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/91)

Comment: Ссылка до сих пор не исправлена.